# Neo4j algo.unionFind equivalent with new Graph Data Science Library

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo, graph-data-science

I have a cypher projection that used algo.unionFind in Neo4j. However, that algorithim has been deprecated. My query was:

`CALL algo.unionFind('MATCH (n) WHERE n.dtype=\"VALUE\" RETURN id(n) AS id','MATCH p=(n)-[]-(m) WHERE n.dtype=\"VALUE\" AND m.dtype=\"VALUE\" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target',  {write:true, partitionProperty:\"partition\", graph:'cypher'}) YIELD nodes, setCount, loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis`

I was hoping to find an equivalent approach with the Graph Data Science Library that runs the query and writes a new property `partition` in my nodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm has been renamed to `gds.wcc.write` in the new GDS library.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to incorporate the cypher projection as well? In ```gds.wcc.write``` I only see the parameters for writing the property.

Comment: You can use nodeQuery and relationshipQuery parameters

Comment: Thanks! I used ```gds.graph.create.cypher``` and passed in nodeQuery and relationshipQuery parameters. Then ```gds.wcc.write``` for writing in the new property